# Dynamically changing the value of <input> with the changing value of an int

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

In this `foreach` i am calling images stored in the database in table "Treasure":

```
//the rest of the code is omitted for reading purposes.

foreach (var item in tresh)
  {
   if (item.itemImage != null)
      {
        string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(item.itemImage);
        imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);


        <img id="@item.treasureID" class="thisImage" src="@imageSource" width="100" height="100" onclick="return MakeSure()" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddentreasure_id" value="@item.treasureID" />
        } 
  }
```

Now what happens with the value of the hidden `<input>` is it stores the value of the first image id, and does not dynamically change as the `foreach` increases.

How can i make the value of the `<input>` dynamically change with the `treasure_ID` of the images in this loop.

This is where i am using the value of the `<input>`

```
function MakeSure() {

                var id = $("[id$=hiddentreasure_id]").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/MakeSure",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html and `$('#hiddentreasure_id').val()` will only ever return the value of the first element with `id="hiddentreasure_id"` Use class names and relative selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to already be writing out correctly.

Each of the hidden  elements do have the same ID though.  ID is supposed to be unique per page.  Your MakeSure() javascript is just selecting the first element with that ID it encounters (which will always have same same value because you're always selecting the same one).

You can pass the ID value into MakeSure() in your onclick.  Something along the lines of...

```
onclick="return MakeSure(@(item.treasureID))"
```

and

```
function MakeSure(id) {
```